# System users password has expired

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have just tried to login to my db via sql developer as system so i can create a new user. It has come with an error that the password has expired.

I have googled a bit but cannot see how to reset the system user password. I guess this is a security issue.

My problem is how can I log in as system if the password has expired? How can I unexpire the password without logging in as System users. I seem to be stuck here in a loop where I cannot reset the password expiration.

Comment: Go to SQL Plus and try to connect as sys using existing password, it will ask you to reset password, you can then reset password and login again with new password in SQL developer

Comment: thanks @rs This worked. I accept this as an answer if you had done it as an answer rather than a comment

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Open up `cmd.exe` and type in SQLPLUS

```
 Enter user-name: SYSTEM
 Enter password: the expired password
```

It will now let you type in a new password for the SYSTEM user

Comment: @SaurabhBhoomkar Well that message hints that a connection to a database was requested using a connect identifier, and the connect identifier specified could not be resolved. make sure the tnsnames.ora file exists and there are no syntax errors in it.

Comment: And you can use old one as a new one :)

Comment: I'm logged in, but now what command is required to reset the pwd?

Answer (score 8):

If SQLPLUS is not available, you can also reset an expired password from within SQL Developer:

- Save your connection information (if not done already)
- Right click on your connection
- Click on the “Reset Password” option in the menu, enter old/new password blah blah blah

Answer (score 1):

If someone drops by from a Google search but uses IntelliJ: 
You can reset the system password in the connection properties' "Advanced" tab. There you can set the new one as a value for the `oracle.jdbc.newPassword` key.